# Why passing React component reference as prop is better than passing component instance

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find a case that shows why passing a React component reference as a prop is better than passing a component instance

For example, if I have a component of Card

```
interface CardProps {
  cardContentComponent: React.FC<unknown>;
  cardContentComponentProps: Record<string, unknown>;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({
  cardContentComponent: CardContentComponent,
  cardContentComponentProps,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      <CardContentComponent {...cardContentComponentProps} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Then I can use it like that

```
const p = { text: "hi there" };

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card cardContentComponent={CardContent} cardContentComponentProps={p} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Where CardContent can be

```
interface CardContentProps {
  text: string;
}

const CardContent: React.FC<CardContentProps> = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Card Content {text}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardContent;
```

And then the Card component is more generic

My question is why this approach for the Card component is better than passing the CardContent as an instance like that

The Card component:

```
interface CardProps {
  cardContentComponent: React.ReactElement;
}

const Card: React.FC<CardProps> = ({ cardContentComponent }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Card Title</h3>
      {cardContentComponent}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

The App component:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card cardContentComponent={<CardContent text={"hi there"} />} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Can someone please give a proper example of a scenario where the first approach is better than the second?

Thanks !!

Comment: Where did you get the information that one is better than other? They are different approaches depending on your needs. Alternatively you can even pass a render prop. It all depends on the situation

Comment: Intuitively it seemed to me that the reference approach is better. But maybe it's not. @OktayYuzcan Can you give me some examples that shows when each of these approaches is better than the other? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I remember passing just a reference to a react component as a props. Sometimes, it might be necessary to create a function that could do changes to some react components that "look different" but that might have some property/call back/function in common or that might belong to a group of react components that you know how to identify within that group. Then, by just passing the reference you could call, for example, a "common callback" that belongs to the respective referenced component. References are like "pointers". Depending on how well the code is written the use of references might become hard to follow.

Imaging you have a tree of nodes. Each node represents a "React component". The descendants in this tree are React components called from the "father's return section". If for each descendant it is passed as props the reference to its father then it is possible for each descendant to know who is its father and its ancestors. Can this be done without passing the reference of a father as props? I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks Jose, but I was looking for an example that would demonstrate the advantages of passing the component as a reference. Not sure I understood this answer